# Ruby: Open Module's singleton

Tags: ruby, singleton

So in a Ruby class, you can use an idiom such as `class << self` like the following:

```
class SalesOrganization
  def self.find_new_leads
    ...
  end
  class << self
     include ::NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation
     add_transaction_tracer :find_new_leads, :category => :task
  end
end
```

My question is what if `SalesOrganization` is actually a `Module` instead of `Class`. Is this doing what I'm hoping it would do, or am I opening up some black magic that I shouldn't be dabbling with?

```
# Potentially terrible code
module SalesOrganization
      def self.find_new_leads
        ...
      end
      class << self
         include ::NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation
         add_transaction_tracer :find_new_leads, :category => :task
      end
end
```

How do I access a modules singleton class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not releasing any black magic. You can define singleton methods on any object, including a module (an instance of the `Module` class):

```
module M; end

def M.a
  "a"
end

M.a  # => "a"
```

The approaches you suggest work too:

```
module M
  def self.b
    "b"
  end
end

M.b  # => "b"

module M
  class << self
    def c
      "c"
    end
  end
end

M.c  # => "c"
```

You can also use `instance_eval` if your method definitions aren't known until runtime:

```
module M; end

M.instance_eval <<EOF
  def d
    "d"
  end
EOF

M.d  # => "d"
```

Of course, modules like `NewRelic...` may make assumptions about the classes/modules into which they're included, so you have to be careful there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood what you want to archive. But if you want to write the definition of including `C` in a module `B`. And than use `C` in `A` after including `B`, than you can do that this way:

```
module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.include C
  end
end

class A
  include B

  # use C
end
```

That is for your example:

```
module SalesOrganization
  def self.included(base)
    base.include ::NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation
    base.add_transaction_tracer :find_new_leads, :category => :task
  end


  def self.find_new_leads
    ...
  end
end
```

If you now include that SalesOrganization module into a class the class will have the Newrelic stuff included.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the original question on how to open a Module's singleton class. I'm not including that module anywhere to the included method will never trigger. I am just using it as a namespace for now.